# Overloading an operator in a namespace and a sub-namespace in C++17 is ambiguous

Tags: c++, namespaces, operator-overloading, c++17, overloading

I try to overload the `operator<<` in a namespace. Additionally, I want to include a debug namespace within the first namespace, where the `operator<<` does more.

In the main function, I create an object of a class within the first namespace and give it out with std::cout. I expected to have to 'name' the operator before I can do that, as in `using test::operator<<`, but I don't have to.

This leads to my issue:
If I want to use my debug operator now, it is ambiguous and I cannot use it and I don't really understand why.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

namespace test{
    class A{
        std::string str_;
    public:
        explicit A(const std::string& str) : str_{str} {}
        inline std::ostream& toStream(std::ostream& os) const {
            return os << str_ << "\n";
        }
    };
    std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, const A& a) {
        return a.toStream(os);
    }
}

namespace test {
    namespace debug {
        std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, const A& a) {
            std::string info = "\n\tDebug\n"
                "\t\tLine: " + std::to_string(__LINE__) + "\n"
                "\t\tFile: " __FILE__ "\n"
                "\t\tDate: " __DATE__ "\n"
                "\t\tTime: " __TIME__ "\n"
                "\t\tVersion: " + std::to_string(__cplusplus) + "\n";
            return a.toStream(os) << info;
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    test::A a{"Test"};
    if(argc > 1) {
        using test::debug::operator<<;
        // Ambiguous error
        std::cout << a << "\n";
    } else {
        // Don't need it for some reason
        // using test::operator<<;
        std::cout << a << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: can you elaborate why you think it's not ambiguous? they have exactly the same signature.

Comment: I thought I have to explicitly use `using test::operator<<;` to tell the compiler where to find the overload, because it is hidden in the namespace "test".

Comment: The extra debug data will not give you so much though. `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` will always be the file where the `operator<<` is defined. I assume you wanted to get the line and file of where you call?

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that. Yes, correct. I thought the preprocessor uses the file and line where it was called from.

Comment: No, unfortunately not. That's why logging libraries usually use macros, something like: #define LOG(msg) std::cout << __FILE__ << "(" << __LINE__ << "): " << msg << std::endl .

Comment: I see. Thank you. I should change it to this then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I expected to have to 'name' the operator before I can do that, as in using test::operator<<, but I don't have to.

This is because of [Argument Dependent Lookup (ADL)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl).

If you pull the operator from the `debug` namespace into the current scope via the using, this does not "overwrite" the existing operator, they are both avaliable, hence the ambiguity.

There are many ways to deal with it, one possibility is to use a different type for the debug output:

```
namespace test {
    namespace debug {
        struct debug_A {
            const A& data;
            debug_out(const A& a) : a(a) {}
        };

        std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, const debug_A& d) {
            auto& a = d.data;
            std::string info = "\n\tDebug\n"
                "\t\tLine: " + std::to_string(__LINE__) + "\n"
                "\t\tFile: " __FILE__ "\n"
                "\t\tDate: " __DATE__ "\n"
                "\t\tTime: " __TIME__ "\n"
                "\t\tVersion: " + std::to_string(__cplusplus) + "\n";
            return a.toStream(os) << info;
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can call it via

```
std::cout << test::debug::debug_A{ a } << '\n';
```

Answer (score 4):

When you have:

```
using test::debug::operator<<;
std::cout << a << "\n";
```

Lookup for `std::cout << a` is going to find two candidates:

- `test::debug::operator<<(ostream&, A const&)` through regular unqualified lookup, found through the using-declaration.
- `test::operator<<(ostream&, A const&)` through argument-dependent lookup (ADL), since `A` is in namespace `test` so we find the candidates there.

Those two candidates have the same signature, there's nothing at all to differentiate them, so it's ambiguous.

---

The sanest thing to do, in my opinion, is actually to wrap `a`. Write:

```
std::cout << debug{a} << '\n';
```

Where `debug` is just a type that has a member reference to `A`, and has its own custom logging that is more detailed than usual.

Comment: Thank you very much for your anwser. @idclev 463035818's code example helped me a little bit better, that's why I marked his response as the solution, but yours was also very good. I just had to choose one.

Comment: What's the difference between using `using` and defining the `operator<<` in global namespace? When moved to global namespace, there is no error anymore. https://godbolt.org/z/CTDkzE

Comment: @MikaelH There's only regular, unqualified lookup going on here. We go from innermost to outermost scope until we find a candidate and then we stop. So once you find `test::debug::operator<<` you don't keep going. ADL finds nothing.

Comment: Oh, so it does not have anything to do with *namespaces*. If we call `using`, the symbol is pulled *into that scope*, and it will be found unambiguously? (just like having a global variable `int a = 2;` redefined in a scope `{ int a = 3; std::cout << a; // 3}`)